Are the following sentences correct? (1) Whatever you do, I love you. AND (2) What you do, I love you


Whatever you do, I love you.
What you do, I love you.


Whatever you do and what you do are both noun clauses, but I feel that the first sentence is correct, while the second is not. Why is that so? How can whatever make the sentence structure Noun, S + V correct even though it normally isn't?
Please kindly cite credible sources for your answer if possible! Thank you!

Don't know why this question got a downvote.

It's irrelevant that what [verb + subject] and whatever [verb + subject] can both be used as noun phrases. The difference is only whatever can also be used as...

...a nominal relative introducing a qualifying subordinate clause equivalent to a conditional or concessive clause: no matter what; (frequently implying opposition, equivalent to a conditional clause with though) notwithstanding anything that.
Formerly also with third person singular verb in the subjunctive (e.g. whatever happen ‘if any (sort of) thing happen’, ‘whether one thing or another happen’).
Often with ellipsis of the verb (e.g. whatever its merits ‘whatever its merits may be’).
Oxford English Dictionary

As the final sentence above points out, the verb needn't be explicitly present:

Whatever your faults [may be], I love you.


Nice return of serve.  Side note:  It's my understanding that a Brit might write  "Whatever did she say when you told her that??" instead of "What ever did she say when you told her that??"   Is that right?

Whatever do you mean by that? Almost everyone everywhere writes that whatever as a single word. Are you implying a significant pause between the two parts, or significant stress on the second part, or both? I personally wouldn't include ever there anyway - if I wanted to pointedly add stress, it would be "What exactly / on earth do you mean by that?"

It's a slightly old-fashioned mode of speaking -- from people who were already middle-aged when the internet arrived.  Fairly common down South in the US. Both a pause and emphasis. "What ever do you mean?"  Very different prosody from "Whatever you do, don't mention cats."  .

Well, I suppose sometimes people say things like emphatic Abso... ...lutely! with a "spliced-in" pause in polite company (or f✱cking in impolite company). But Google NGrams obviously wouldn't find many examples of abso lutely, would they? I'm more used to hearing Whatever! with stress on the first syllable lately - as a very dismissive way of saying "I couldn't care less" ( "I could care less", in that peculiar American version! :)

They are two separate words in that form of statement.  Like "How ever did you manage to get such a quick response from them?"  The utterance expresses surprise that you were able to get such a quick response. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Concise_Oxford_English_Dictionary/4XycAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22How+ever+did+you+manage%22&pg=PA692&printsec=frontcover

again, I'd expect How ever did you manage? to be written as a single word, as reflected by that usage chart. Where the 2-word form isn't quite so unusual as What ever do you mean?, but they're both "minority" usages. Note that NGrams are case-sensitive, so both my linked charts only show utterances beginning with the specified nominal relative. I don't see much scope for different contexts / meanings.
